# Help with Port Forwarding for College Project

Tags: camera, picamera, port-forwarding

Hello Guys im doing a group college project for my final year it involves a CCTV type project using the raspberry pi camera and a website with a php login system to the website, I have a Pan Tilt hat with web buttons everything works fine locally but I want to get it working so you can access it from everywhere, we are allowed to connect to the college Wifi but we are not allowed to Port Forward or anything like that.

My question is, 
What can I do to get the website public with Port Forwarding?
Can I connect to my home network from the raspberry that is in a different location because my home network allows port forwarding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to raspberry pi outside of local network without port forwarding](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53954/how-to-connect-to-raspberry-pi-outside-of-local-network-without-port-forwarding)

Comment: Also check out answers to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85844/remote-access-using-reverse-ssh-tunnel-without-port-forwarding)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running everything local on the Raspberry Pi, you can connect the RaspberryPi which is connected to your college WiFi to your home computer, without hacking or opening your college Wifi using [secure socket tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol) or [SSH Tunneling](https://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/ssh-tunnelling-explained/).

From your Rpi you could establish a outbound socket connection to your home computer.  For example Rpi port 80 -> homecomputer port 8080

Worth noting that you don't have to open your home computer port 8080.  Only rely on the ssh protocol/service to access.  You may have to make firewall changes at home as well.

This would allow you to access on your home computer your Rpi website on port 80 from your desktop home computer using localhost:8080 or similar.

Keep in mind that connecting a machine that is hosted on one person's network to another network may break a rule! Be responsible and learn. :)

Comment: Mark, I will contact IT services in my college to see if it is allowed. If they allow me to do this would there be any chance of getting slight help doing this because it sounds quite advanced

Comment: Yes -- I can aid you one evening.

Comment: I have gotten in contact with IT Services and they said SSH Tunneling is fine. I need to find a guide somewhere that will lead me in the correct direction to get this to work.